# Set Limit 3 to a SQL with Case and Left Join?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, database, sqlite

I have a working SQL code that retrieves all the scores of a hockey team. I would like to set `Limit 3` or `<= 3`:

```
my = cursor_test.execute('''SELECT Next.ClubHome,
                            CASE
                            WHEN Next.ClubHome = Result.ClubHome then Result.ScoreHome
                            WHEN Next.ClubHome = Result.ClubAway then Result.ScoreAway
                            END as score
                            FROM NextMatch Next
                            LEFT JOIN ResultMatch Result ON Next.ClubHome in (Result.ClubHome, Result.ClubAway)
                            ''')

for row in my.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

Let me explain the question better:

1. Observe the next **Chicago**, **New York** and **Dallas** hockey matchs in the `NextMatch` table: are featured in `ClubHome`

**NEXTMATCH**

| ClubHome | ClubAway | Tournament |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Chicago | Minnesota | NHL |
| New York | Los Angeles | NHL |
| Dallas | Vegas Gold | NHL |

2. In the `ResultMatch` table, I would like to retrieve the last 3 overall scores of Chicago, New York and Dallas (`ScoreHome` or `ScoreAway`). So I would like this output:

   Chicago: 2

   Chicago: 0

   Chicago: 1

   New York: 2

   New York: 3

   New York: 2

   Dallas: 4

   Dallas: 3

   Dallas: 1

**RESULTMATCH**

| ClubHome | ClubAway | Tournament | Round | ScoreHome | ScoreAway |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Toronto | CHICAGO | NHL | 8 | 1 | 2 |
| New York | Vegas | NHL | 8 | 2 | 3 |
| CHICAGO | Dallas | NHL | 7 | 0 | 4 |
| Ottawa | New York | NHL | 7 | 3 | 3 |
| CHICAGO | Buffalo Sab | NHL | 6 | 1 | 0 |
| Vegas | CHICAGO | NHL | 6 | 4 | 2 |
| New York | Dallas | NHL | 5 | 2 | 3 |
| Dallas | Buffalo Sab | NHL | 5 | 1 | 2 |

A code that can be USEFUL for the solution is the following. However, it only retrieves the last 3 Scorehome results (and not the ScoreAway):

```
x = cursor2.execute('''SELECT ClubHome,
                       FROM (SELECT NextMatch.ClubHome, NextMatch.ClubAway, ResultMatch.ScoreHome,
                       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NextMatch.ClubHome ORDER BY ResultMatch.ScoreHome DESC) AS rn
                       FROM NextMatch
                       INNER JOIN ResultMatch ON NextMatch.ClubHome = ResultMatch.ClubHome) t
                       WHERE rn <= 3
                       ORDER BY ClubHome ASC''')
```

How can I modify my (first code) and add `Limit 3` or `<= 3` to get what I ask for in the outputs example? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it in SQL only and not filtering the results in Python, you could use the windowing function ROW_NUMBER:

```
SELECT clubHome, score FROM (
SELECT Next.clubhome,
       CASE
         WHEN Next.ClubHome = Result.ClubHome then Result.ScoreHome
         WHEN Next.ClubHome = Result.ClubAway then Result.ScoreAway
       END as score, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY next.clubHome ORDER BY round DESC) rowNum
  FROM nextmatch Next
  JOIN resultmatch Result ON Next.clubhome in (Result.clubhome, Result.clubaway)
) WHERE rowNum <= 3;
```

SQLFiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xrLpLwSu783AQHrwD8Fq4t/0

Comment: Does not work. There is some error

Comment: I guess for "some error", there is most likely "some solution"?

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand what's wrong with your code. Your idea is right, but there is some minor mistake I think. Can you double check your code please? Thank you

Comment: Have you checked my SQLFiddle?